# Location still null after user enable location usage

Tags: java, android, location, android-gps

When I try to get the last known location of the user, right after the user has agreed to the use of his own location by the app, I have found that the location is still null.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode){
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                        getLastKnowLocation();
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:{
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Location not enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    default:{
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

protected void getLastKnowLocation() {
        if (checkPermission(FINE_LOCATION) == DENIDED) {
            requestPermissionLocation(OBTAINGLASTKNOWLOCATION_REQUESTCODE);
            return;
        }
        flpc.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
                if (location != null && onSuccessListener != null) onSuccessListener.onSuccess(location);
                else {
                    displayLocationSettingsRequest(onSuccessListener);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

There's anyway to force the app to get the user's location?
By the way, I'm **not** using any map here.

Comment: What have you done in the requestPermissionLocation(OBTAINGLASTKNOWLOCATION_REQUESTCODE) method ?

Comment: I just ask the user permission for the app to have access to his location information

Comment: getLastKnownLocation can always return null.  Location being enabled does NOT mean the phone is actively trackign it.  Use requestSingleUpdate instead if you must get a location.  getLaskKnownLocation is an optimization for speedy results only and should not be relied on.

Comment: @GustavoOliveira , Have you implemented the onRequestPermissionsResult method?

Comment: @ShubhamRaitka I do not have, but it is not something related to the permission to access the location information. This can happen after the user gives the permission and, for some reason, he decides not to use his location anymore, for example, his smartphone may be at a low battery level.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the advice, I tried but unfortunaly is not working, the location still null.

Comment: So you are not able to get the location even if the permission has been granted and Location is ON ?

Comment: Exactly. If the Location is off and the user turns on, the location still null.